# Is there any algorithm for number decomposition?

Tags: java, algorithm

Recently I faced "2 easy problems, which can be solved in an hour". I'm not really familiar with competitive programming, so it wasn't that easy for me, and I came up only with brute force methods, so now I'm interested if my solution even works and if there is better solution.

The problem was:

*Given N(2 digits or more), find minimal number such that the product of its digits equals to N. If it's impossible, return 0.*

My solution in java looked like this

```
int getNumber(int N) {
    int i = 25;
    while(i < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        if(digitsMult(i) == N)
            return i;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also would be nice if you could check the second problem as well.

*Given N, return X, such that*

*X > N, X - simple, X - palindrome*

Here I used brute force as well

```
int getPrimePalindrome(int N) {
    int i = N;
    while(i < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        if(isPalindrome(i))
            if(isPrime(i))
                return i;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

boolean isPalindrome(int n) {
    String num = Integer.toString(n);
    String reverse = new StringBuffer(n).reverse().toString();
    return num.equals(reverse);
}

boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if(n == 2)
        return true;
    if(n % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    for(int i = 3; i*i <= n; i+=2)
        if(n % i == 0)
             return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: "so now I'm interested if my solution even works" did you test it? Is there any problem you are facing?

Comment: You cannot throw your questions and problems in that way; ask one clear question at a time

Comment: @NadimBaraky i asked 1 question which is in the top and in bold and it is really big. It says "Is there any algorithm for number decomposition?". Other questions are optional.

Comment: ok, I meant no offense in the above comment; I wanted to try to help and enhance my knowledge.

Comment: @Pshemo I didn't test it, because it was kind of pre-interview test, and I had to write code without compiler. I really meant is it looking good enough from the point of view of experienced person?

Comment: @NadimBaraky no offence as well, thanks for comment. I just don't understand how and where should you ask such kinds of questions - you see, i had 2 problems which I solved somehow and wanted to see opinion of experienced programmers.

Comment: @FalAlexandr but now you have access to computer (or online IDE) so you can test it. Anyway questions like "is it good from point of view .." are most likely primarily opinion-based which makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. But you could ask "how can I improve this code which purpose is to [description of task]". If you are *sure* that your code *works* then you can even post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, if there is some problem with code then Stack Overflow is OK (you just need to add problem description). Also two separate tasks should be split in two separate questions.

Comment: So you should [ask one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: @Pshemo okay, got it, thank you

Comment: You accepted an answer that didn't answer what you say was your question "is there an algorithm for number decomposition". Maybe that wasn't your question?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of question is very common for coding interviews.  'Brute forcing' as you put it is the only way, however, I think what they are looking for is clever optimisations,

For example your `isPalindrome` can be more efficient - you only need to check the first half matches the end half reversed, not the whole thing.

Secondly, you don't want to be calculating your prime stack inside the inner loop every single time.  I would move `isPrime` to be the outer `if` which would allow you to maintain the complete list of primes and not have to calculate it each time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really was pre-interview test. Never done it before, so "clever optimisation" kind of confused me, because I thought that optimisation means using some good algorithm. Now I understand what it really means.

Comment: Can you please explain how would moving `isPrime` help? I understand, that it could help if I need to reuse this code. Like if it was some kind of application, I would do this in cycle in `main` and I could have `ArrayList` of prime numbers. Did you mean something like this?

Comment: If you look at your isPrime impl you are asking it to calculate all primes up to n everytime.  If you make it the main loop then the need for this recalc is removed.

Comment: @FalAlexandr Since palindromic numbers are asymptotically less dense than primes, there is actually algorithmic improvements to be had. For example, you could enumerate the first half of the palindrome, and then check if the whole thing is prime. Otherwise, say X = 98760000, you would need almost 10^4 steps just to get to the first palindrome

Comment: @Niklas can you give a worked example?

Comment: @Lee Do you mean if I am willing to write code implementing the algorithm I just described? No I leave that as an exercise to the reader. But by enumerating the palindromes directly you can get expected runtime of O(log X) instead of Omega(sqrt X), the latter of which is what OP proposes.

Comment: @Lee `isPrime` is checking if number is prime by dividing it by all numbers up to sqrt(number), am I wrong? At least this is what I wanted it to do...

Comment: Yes but it checks all the numbers up to that point again and again

Comment: @Lee is there any other way to check if number is prime? The fact that previous number I checked wasn't prime can't help me anyhow. Am I missing something? To check if number is prime, I MUST check if it can be divided by any number up to sqrt(n), am I worng?

Comment: That's why you need to restructure the loops.

Comment: @NiklasB. What do you mean by "enumerating"? Instead of searching just construct it somehow?

Comment: @Lee I don't really understand the difference between `if(isPalindrome(n)) if(isPrime(n))` and `if(isPrime(n)) if(isPalindrome(n))`. Now I see that it looks kind of ridiculous, because it should really be `if(isPalindrome(n) && isPrime(n))`.

Comment: I think what @NiklasB was referring to is the fact that if your potential number starts with a 2 then we know it can be skipped because if it passes the palindrome test then it would end with a 2 and hence definitely not be a candidate - therefore you can skip all 200 - 299, all 400-499, all 2000 - 2999 etc etc etc

Comment: Regarding the restructure of the loops: you currently have a `while` going from 0 -> Max and also and second inner loop going from 3 -> Max.  If you restructure you can get rid of the second loop.

Comment: @FalAlexandr It is easy to enumerate all palindromes by just enumerating their first halves. E.g. the palindromes between  1000 and 10000 are 1001, 1111, 1221, 1331, 1441, 1551, ... 9779, 9889, 9999. And there are only 90 of them. By looking at the first half of N, you can immediately determine the smallest palindrome larger than N. And with probability of roughly 1/log N it is prime (that's because there are around m / log m primes amongst the integers 1 to m). If it's not prime, just increment the first half and check again, until you find a prime. Use e.g. Miller-Rabin for primality testing

Comment: I mainly commented on this answer primarily because of the "is the only way" part without any proof or even intuition of why that is the case

Comment: @Niklas yes, I got it, thank you for the answer. Though I really doubt I could come up with this really basic idea in stressfull situation...